offload long running function in javascript/node
I'd like to await a function, call it
runThirdPartyCall()

however, I don't know how long this will take ahead of time. If it takes longer than 30 seconds, i'd like to return from the request early, but still be able to reason about what runThirdPartyCall() returns.
Is this possible to do with workers? I see that javascript cannot directly hand over the execution of a function or the promise it returns to another thread or process once it has started, so i'm wondering if there are any alternatives.
I'm stuck wondering about the general problem, when you have a third party call of which you don't know how long it will take, and if it ends up taking too long you want to go and inform the client/move on to other things

if it ends up taking too long you want to go and inform the client/move on to other things Thats a great use case for the asynchronous of node. It takes what it takes to complete the operation... What you want/describe is a queue system.

yup, but how do i offload an already running function to something else that can listen for it once it's completed?

but how do i offload an already running function You cant. Thats not how javascript/node.js works. Thats what the queue is for. Add your operatoin to the queue, and move on. When the operation is completed, do whatever you want. Clarify your problem. Its not clear what you want.

i want to await a function call. If that function call takes longer than N seconds, i want to return early to avoid timeouts, and notify the client this process is taking a long time. While this is going on i want to see when the function call finishes so I can work off of it

Use the message facility to communicate the answer back to your mainline from the worker: -
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) 
{
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'init':
      initThread(data.load);
      break;
    case 'stop':
      self.postMessage({'success' : true});
      self.close(); 
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage({'success' : false, 'msg' : data.msg});
  };
}, false);

Mainline
    facFinder = new Worker("facfinder.js");
    facFinder.addEventListener('message', workerInit, false);
    
    facFinder.postMessage({'cmd' : 'init', 'load' : xmlhttp.responseText});


sorry maybe this is clear but i'm a bit confused by this code. Would it be possible to for example, offload the process to the thread only if it's taking longer than 5 seconds (as an example)? So we hit the code, await it, 5 seconds is up, and we offload it to a worker to get the return value

@sf8193 That's not generally how thereads work. To do what you want you need to instead re-architecture your code so the function is NEVER already running. You offload the function to the thread before it it running ALWAYS and signal if it is taking too long asynchronously. For example you can return a promise of either the result or another promise if result is not ready in time. Another possibility is to potentially return an async generator so you can wait in a while loop (if you're in the while loop it's taking too long but if you skip the while loop it returns quickly) etc.

I think your requirements need to be clearer, but anyway: -
This code does NOT start on the UI thread and then miraculously switch to a WORKER thread but I believe it could match your requirements.
Mainline: -
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let wait, worker, timer, taskDone;
    
    document.getElementById("startIt").addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
        const TooLong = 5000;
        e.target.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("stopIt").disabled = false;
        worker = new Worker("demo_worker.js");
        worker.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e.data;
        });
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            taskDone(-1);
            }, TooLong);
        let result = new Promise((taskResolver) => {
            taskDone = taskResolver;
            });
        let myStatus = await result;
        if (myStatus == -1)
            console.warn("It's taking too long");
    });
    
    document.getElementById("stopIt").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        e.target.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("startIt").disabled = false;
        if (worker != undefined)
        {
            worker.terminate();
            taskDone(1);
        }
        worker = undefined;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
<button id="startIt">Start Worker</button>
<button id="stopIt" disabled>Stop Worker</button>

</body>
</html>

demo_worker.js
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
  postMessage(++i);
  setTimeout("timedCount()",500);
}

timedCount();

